# Angular 6 return JSON result intead of HTML template

Tags: json, angular, httpresponse

Is it possible to return JSON result from Angular instead of the HTML template coz we want to build something similar to a API-server? Thanks.

Here is the example that return the HTML template, how can we just return JSON without using template?

What I want to return is just a simple json result instead of HTML.

```
{"ID" : "1", "Name" : "Apple"}
```

Here is the code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-noresultsfound',
  templateUrl: './noresultsfound.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./noresultsfound.component.css']
})
export class NoresultsfoundComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() txtval: string;

  constructor(private app: AppConstants) { }

  noresultsfound = this.app.noresultsfound;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Alex

Comment: For example..??

Comment: Thanks but still it's not clear what you are asking! Do you want to return JSON? like `{"key" : "value"}` etc or HTML like `<div>This is HTML content</div>`.

Comment: and what you mean by return? From function? from API?

Comment: You need to be clear what you want to return from where (API, function, input etc....) So we can help you

Comment: Thanks again, I updated as well. I just want to build a mock server to return some simple JSON result.

Comment: Hi you can create a json file (filename.json) and directly call it using Http or you can create a constant file that export your json

Comment: How can I setup the routing to return different json file? e.g. /post/1, /post/2 and return different json? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, he meant that pure JSON should be returned to who ever requested it by endpoint request. At least i faced something like this.
For static json, i've found an answer: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5029

bresleveloper commented on 6 Jul 2018
1. ng-build with your index.html set properly with its components. (or conditional app-components)
2. rename and copy the rendered to (for example) /src/search.html
3. in angular.json (angular-cli.json for pre v5) find "assets":

```
"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/search.html",
"src/assets"
],
```

browse localhost:4200/search.html
enjoy :)

Interesting part comes when u try to generate that json somehow, with browser not being involved - like some automatic service sends a request to some angular endpoint, like: hosname/statistics and in response, it receives a json which depends on number of pictures and headers on this current hosname, like {siteName: 'test', pictures: 10, headers: 1}.